# How to stretch and compress the length, width and height of a cube using keyboard?

Tags: javascript, three.js

When resizing the cube, one face does not move and other faces change the position or size. The height/depth/width need to be stretched or compressed according to the keyboard.

I've built a cube, but I can only modify the position of the cube

```
cube.position.y -= 1
```

but the height, depth, width cannot be changed.

```
cube.geometry.parameters.height += 1
```

```
document.addEventListener("keydown", onDocumentKeyDown, false);
            function onDocumentKeyDown(event) {
                var keyCode = event.which;
                // up
                if (keyCode == 87) {
                    mesh.geometry.parameters.height += 1;
                    // down
                } else if (keyCode == 83) {
                    mesh.position.y -= 1;
                    // left
                } else if (keyCode == 65) {
                    mesh.position.x -= 1;
                    // right
                } else if (keyCode == 68) {
                    mesh.position.x += 1;
                    // space
                } else if (keyCode == 32) {
                    mesh.position.x = 0.0;
                    mesh.position.y = 0.0;
                }
                render();
            };
```

The desired effect is shown below：http://product-cdn-tagging.oss-cn-beijing.aliyuncs.com/test/3d.gif

Answer (score 3):

Modifying the `parameters` property has not effect after a geometry was created. If you want to transform the width, height or depth of a cube, please use [Object3D.scale](https://threejs.org/docs/index.html#api/en/core/Object3D.scale) instead. This approach is demonstrated in the following fiddle.

https://jsfiddle.net/xovwfe8t/

`Object3D.position`, `Object3D.rotation` and `Object3D.scale` represent the local transformation of a 3D object. These properties should be your primary interface if you want to apply a transformation in 3D space.

`three.js R 104`